# Перевод в произвольную систему счисления

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В C++ для перевода целых десятичных чисел в произвольную систему счисления есть функция *itoa()*. А что делать для чисел типа *double*?

Comment: Где-где есть функция `itoa`? Вы чего-то путаете. Она есть в старых сишных библиотеках (для десятичной системы счисления, в современных её нет) и библиотеке имени Borland C++ (видел там). Там да -- с разными системами счисления (хотя и с весьма старнным поведением).

А для чисел double? Зачёты замучили?

Comment: Если бы зачет, а то экзамен =) В VS2013 в библиотеке cstdlib есть такая itoa и прекрасно отрабатывает на целых. Но неужели для double придется самому все писать?

Comment: @LiGhT_WoLF, что конкретно Вам нужно?

Получить из *double* его символьную запись в `char[]` в **произвольной** системе счисления? Таких не знаю. 

А в десятичную -- смотрите `man 3 sprintf`.

Если очень надо, то самому писать придется. Видимо используя в цикле деление на основание этой системы счисления.

Comment: @avp прав, придется писать самому. Делите целую часть на основание системы счисления, получая в виде остатка числовые значения цифр, пока целая часть не станет равной нулю. Обратите внимание, что цифры вы получаете, начиная с младшей. Дробную часть надо умножать на основание системы счисления, последовательно получая цифры (целая часть результата), начиная со старшей. Только надо знать, сколько разрядов после запятой вам нужно, т.к. десятичиная дробь может оказаться иррациональной в вашей системе счисления и цикл станет бесконечным.

Comment: @paulgri, десятичная дробь НЕ может оказаться иррациональной. Но может стать периодической.

Comment: @BuilderC, спасибо, я именно об этом, а иррациональной она действительно не станет по определению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itoa()` занимается тем, что делает "Integer TO ASCII". Т.е. целочисленную **бинарную** переменную в однобайтовый **строковый** эквивалент. Т.е. аналог `Integer.toString()` в Java. Да, основание СС можно указать, но ASCII-to-ASCII оно не сделает, а `int` как был бинарным, так и останется.

В `cstdlib` есть, как минимум `ftoa` и `dtoa` (с этим не уверен) для `float` и `double` соответственно.

Comment: **Integer.toString** - это, вероятно, из Java, но явно не из C#

Comment: Ну что ж вы так категоричны? С названием типа ошибся, да, пардон, но Int32.ToString() имеет место быть.